# How to use switch block?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I thing I have a mistake about usage of switch block. Because when I run it , C values always take 298 value (not start with 1 to 298).  When I change constant 298 value , c value is changed but it still only the changed value. I cant declare initial value of C1 as starting value 1 (maybe the mistake is that). I want that at every cycle plot(c,a1); hold on;  while C value increasing. Thanks

[image]

ınside the t>=298 block

[image]

in function

```
function [a1,a2,a3,c1] = fcn(c)

%#codegen
c1=c

[a1,a2,a3]=fff(c)
```

in plot function

```
function fcnplot(z,t)
%#codegen
coder.extrinsic('plot')
plot(z,t,'-or')
hold on;
```

Comment: @am304   I explanied more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation about the [Switch](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/switch.html) block (which you still haven't shown us how you have configured)?

In your case the control input is a boolean signal, so you should set the criteria for passing the first input to `u2 >= Threshold` with the `Threshold` parameter set to `1` (check the doc), buit the first input should be 298, **NOT** the output of the sum block.